scheduled batch file stops running and reports error
I have a batch file that contains the following line:
@robocopy E:\ G:\  /DCOPY:DAT /xd $* syste*  /xf ~* /s /xo /np /copyall /log:c:\back-EG.txt
It is scheduled to run on the first day of month. I noticed that it didn't run this month. The log file has the date of "3/1/2024." When running it manually in a cmd window, I got the following error message:
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #13 : "/log:c:\back-EG.txt"

   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?

This batch file had given no problems before. I don't understand why it is not running now, not even in a cmd window.
This is on Windows 11 Pro, built 22631.3296.

try making this file back-EG.txt first and then run it. Do you still get the error?

In theory, it will create the log file if it doesn't exist. But creating it might help rule things out. Does the account this runs under have write-access to the root of C:? Any change if you use the "log+" variety so it will append rather than overwrite? Maybe a copy/paste changed the hyphen in back-EG.txt to a lookalike character. Try typing the command from scratch to eliminate that possibility.

Also, try removing some of the other options to see if you can get a smaller example that still exhibits the same problem. (Unlikely to help much, because the error makes it pretty clear that it is unhappy about the log parameter.)

Thanks for the replies. I logged in the default Administrator account and ran the batch file again. This time there was no problem. It seems the other account was the problem. Although the other account is a member of the administrators group, it has not write privilege to write to C:.
